# Energy transfer between modes of linear chain of harmonic oscillators?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators

Consider a one dimensional chain of N classical point masses interacting with harmonic neighbor forces (with periodic boundaries for specificity). If the positions and velocities are prepared in a configuration corresponding to a specific oscillation mode, can the energy be transferred to other modes ? Or does the chain oscillate in that prepared mode forever ?

Intuitively I do not see a reason why the energy should be transferred to other modes, but I am not sure. However supposing that is the case, does the chain return to that  mode if small random disturbance is added at some time ? How is the stability of this mode to perturbations ?

Comment: what is "harmonic neighbor forces"? and how do masses interact with each other?

Comment: Each point is harmonically bonded to its two neighbors, this is just the classical harmonic linear chain.

Comment: this is something that is not known to me - "harmonically bonded to its two neighbors,"

Comment: how can anything be harmonically bounded? are atoms harmonically bound in molecules or not?

Comment: The force between point (i) and point (i+1) is zero if the distance between them is x_0, and the force increases linearly in the deviation from that distance. Does that help you ?

Comment: yes, thank you. In this system, there are only modes of the linear chain. I don't see how you'd define modes of individual masses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each normal mode is an independent collective harmonic motion with a single frequency. If the initial conditions *excite* only one normal mode, that motion goes on forever. Of course, this is true in an ideal world without dissipation and without deviations from pure linear elastic interactions.

The interesting question is what is the key ingredient introducing an effective transfer of energy from one mode to another. One naive expectation is that even a weak non-linear coupling would be enough to allow a significant transfer of energy from the initially excited mode(s) and the others. That was the mechanism people thought to allow to establish the equipartition of energy in a system of perturbed linear chains of oscillators.

It came as a surprise the indication from the pioneering simulation by [Pasta Fermi, Ulam and Tsingou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Pasta%E2%80%93Ulam%E2%80%93Tsingou_problem) that this is not the case. It is not enough to add a non-linear term to the interaction. One also has to overcome a threshold of energy to allow a significant transfer of energy between the oscillator modes. This is a signal of a deep result in Classical Mechanics: the [Kolmogoroff-Arnold-Moser (KAM) theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold%E2%80%93Moser_theorem).  The main content of the theorem is that small perturbations of an integrable system are not able to destroy its qualitative behavior in the phase-space.

Comment: And the remaining question : How does the linear system respond to random perturbations ? If energy is pumped through random noise, does it just stay random ?

Comment: @YoussefMabrouk, one should provide an explicit coupling to random noise to allow a meaningful answer.

Comment: I am asking for case where the noise is just introduced to the initial data, i.e random numbers are drawn from Gaussian distribution and added to initial displacements and velocities.

Comment: @YoussefMabrouk,.that case is simple: the noise implies that other modes are excited.  If the system remains linear,  each mode continues forever with the same initial eneergy.

Comment: If you take an ideal lossless linear *filter*, that is a reactive $LC$ 2-port, and you excite it with a pure sinusoid then exactly the same frequency sinusoid will be measured at its output port. If you now allow the slightest smooth nonlinearity in the circuit you will get harmonics of said sinusoidal excitations. If your excitation contains several different discrete frequencies then the output will contain the linear integer combinations of these input frequencies whose distribution in *power* is given by the Manley-Rowe relations and can be viewed as the conservation of quanta($h\nu$)/sec.